# nginx error /home/deploy/myapp/current/public/" is forbidden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

I tried the solution of a similar question and many other on stackoverflow but none of them seem to solve this issue. The default niginx "Welcome" page was running even when I configured **/etc/nginx/passenger.conf** and **/etc/nginx/passenger.conf**. It was after I configured the **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default**, by changing the default path to my rails app, I started getting 403 forbidden error.

**This is the error log.**

```
2017/02/20 06:05:17 [error] 27311#27311: *2 directory index of "/home/deploy/Blog/current/public/" is forbidden, client: 111.93.247.206, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "35.154.168.57"
```

My nginx files are as follows.

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user deploy;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##


gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Phusion Passenger config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed passenger or passenger-enterprise
        ##

        # include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
```

**/etc/nginx/passenger.conf**

```
passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.3.1/ruby;
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
#passenger_ruby /usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby;
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default**

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        server_name mydomain.com;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env    production;
        root         /home/deploy/Blog/current/public;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
}
```

The permissions are:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Feb 20 06:00 /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 179 Feb 20 06:35 /etc/nginx/passenger.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1608 Feb 20 06:34 /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Please can somebody tell what am I doing wrong or what have I not done?
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Backup /home/deploy/Blog/current/public
2. `chown -R <nginxuser>:<nginxuser> /home/deploy/Blog/current/public`

`nginxuser`: the user that runs nginx, its probably one of the following: `nginx`, `www-data`, `root`.

Comment: I'm running nginx as 'deploy' as the user. And I ran `chown -R deploy:deploy /home/deploy/Blog/current/public`. Still the same error. 403 forbidden

Comment: please verify the both paths in your `passenger.conf` are correct.

Comment: both the paths `passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.3.1/ruby;`
`passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;` are correct

Comment: please add `passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.3.1/ruby; passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;` to your `nginx.conf` in http block and try again.

Comment: I added those lines inside **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**  file inside the http tag. Now I'm getting a phusion passenger error saying **We're sorry, but something went wrong.
The issue has been logged for investigation. Please try again later.** on the browser.

Comment: `/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:297:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
`Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 34d4b355. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you missing. Please align yourself with my setup on [https://www.wiki11.com](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/xenial/).

Your issue is coming because nginx is trying to search for `index.html` file into `/home/deploy/apps/mll/current/public` which is not present there. 
In order to fix, you will need to add passenger with your nginx.

Instructions to follow.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 561F9B9CAC40B2F7
sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates
```

Add Passenger APT repository

```
sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger xenial main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list'
sudo apt-get update
```

Install passenger and nginx

```
sudo apt-get install -y nginx-extras passenger
```

Now start nginx webserver.

```
sudo service nginx start
```

Next, we need to update the Nginx configuration to point Passenger to the version of Ruby that we're using.

```
sudo vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

And add or uncomment

```
include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;
```

Save and close nginx.conf. Then open `/etc/nginx/passenger.conf`

```
sudo vim /etc/nginx/passenger.conf
```

If you are using .rbenv, then

```
passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby;
```

Or if you are using rvm, then

```
passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.5.0/ruby;
```

Or if you are using system ruby, then

```
passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
```

Next, restart nginx server

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Add `passenger_enabled on;` into your site-enabled/centers or site-enabled/nodeapp file.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /home/deploy/apps/mll/current/public;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name myrailssite.com;
        passenger_enabled on;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Restart nginx server again, `sudo service nginx restart`. Hopefully it should work.

For more details, follow,
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/xenial/